# Powershell Form in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, powershell, user-interface, visual-studio-2015

I am struggling with GUI for powershell in visual studio 2015 enterprise.

Problem is:
I want to build gui for powershell scripts in visual studio. I know how to do it in Powershell ISE however it takes a lot of time to build forms through scripts. I do not want to download Sapien Powershell Studio or Powershell Studio for this purpose. This version has built-in powershell projects, namely: Powershell Module Project and Powershell Script Project. However, once you choose this type of project you are unable to add windows forms. I know it is possible, just look at the video from youtube below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4CsFblKotc&list=UUIrhSHyw-ySF4eQFkt6fQSA&index=10

As you can see guy in the video has ability to add Powershell Form to the project. I cannot do it as the only options I have are:

Powershell Script,
Powershell Test,
Powershell Script Data File,
Powershell Script Module.

I will also add that I do not want to use WPF project for this.

Does anyone know how to enable Powershell Forms in Visual Stuido? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's in his Installed section so clearly he downloaded it from somewhere but as he hasn't replied to the comment on the video from 6 months ago asking the same thing chances are pretty slim.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following:

```
[**Visual Studio 2017 (Any edition, Community edition)**][1]

**[PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017][1]**
```

SOURCE: https://wandering.life/building-windows-forms-powershell-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: Can you add more information about why these are needed?